# How to make an environment out of a command with one argument

Tags: macros, environments

Given any command with one argument `\Command{<arg>}`, I want to be able to define an environment *EnCommand* such that `\begin{EnCommand} <arg> \end{EnCommand}` has the same effect.

In the opposite direction this is, of course, easy to achieve, but I haven't been able to figure out a (general) way to make, say, `\fbox{...}` into something like `\begin{framed} ... \end{framed}`. I am not interested in packages that can take care of particular cases, I am looking for a general method. Is there an easy way to do it?

Comment: While there are standard ways to *almost* do this, in either direction, there is no guaranteed way to make it work in all cases.  Why?  Because, with commands, the argument is absorbed at the time of invocation, whereas the environment contents are not absorbed in advance.  What this means is that if the argument itself tries to change the catcode of a token, it can have no effect on the tokens within the absorbed argument.

Comment: In most cases (if the command really grabs the arg) you should be able to do it with the `b` argument type of \NewDocumentEnvironment, see the xparse documentation.

Comment: For an example of an environment which does not use \newenvironment, see lrbox (source2e.pdf).  It is, however, somewhat fragile.

Comment: `\begin{fbox} ..  \end{fbox}` should work without you having to do anything special !

Comment: @YiannisLazarides you should better try your suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way and basically a one-liner:

```
\newcommand{\Command}[1]{\fbox{#1}} % this is the command

\NewDocumentEnvironment{EnCommand}{+b}{\Command{#1}}{}
```

Full example.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\Command}[1]{\fbox{#1}} % this is the command

\NewDocumentEnvironment{EnCommand}{+b}{\Command{#1}}{}

\begin{document}

Here \Command{abc} with the command

Here \begin{EnCommand}abc\end{EnCommand} with the environment

Here \begin{EnCommand} abc\end{EnCommand} with the environment

Here \begin{EnCommand}abc \end{EnCommand} with the environment

Here \begin{EnCommand} abc \end{EnCommand} with the environment

Here 
\begin{EnCommand}
abc
\end{EnCommand}
with the environment

\end{document}
```

As you see from the picture, spaces are trimmed at either side.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The easy way to convert a macro into an environment is to **use** `lrbox`.

If you use box registers 0-9 instead of a new box, it will be restored afterward automatically.  But it is possible to make global changes to it inside the environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newsavebox{\FBOX}
\newenvironment{Fbox}{\begin{lrbox}{\FBOX}}{\end{lrbox}\fbox{\usebox\FBOX}}

\begin{document}

\begin{Fbox} This is a test \end{Fbox}

\Fbox This is a test\endFbox

\end{document}
```